# 700D live view depth of field not accurate

Tags: canon, macro, depth-of-field, live-view, canon-700d

I shoot with a Canon 700D and I've just bought myself a Sigma 105mm 2.8 Macro lens. I've been loving the new lens but one issue I have is that the depth of field in the live view on the camera's screen does not seem to be accurate. For example, if I change from f/2.8 to f/5.0, the depth of field on the screen doesn't seem to change at all, but when I actually take the photo, it's clear the the depth of field has increased.

I'm just wondering whether I should expect the depth of field to change on the live view as I change the aperture or if this is just something I have to work with? It kind of makes it hard to know what the outcome of my shot is going to be, which with macro can mean the difference between getting a shot of an insect and not (because it's gone by the time you evaluate the exposure and adjust the aperture).

Comment: Related: [What is the depth-of-field preview button on my DSLR supposed to show me?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5069/15871) and [Why do we need a DOF preview button?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/92045/15871)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The camera usually keeps the aperture open as wide as possible while framing the shot. It is only closed to the setting you dialed in when the picture is being taken. This allows for a brighter viewfinder and more of the auto focus points to be used.

As described in [the manual of your camera](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300010905/07/eos-rebelt5i-700d-im7-en.pdf) on page 114, there's a dedicated button to stop down the aperture to the dialed in setting.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I didn't even realise that button was hiding under there!

Comment: It should probably be noted that the DoF Preview button only works when in the 'Creative Zone' exposure modes: P-S-A-M.

Comment: @MichaelClark Or, in case of most Canon DSLRs, Av-Tv-P-M.

Comment: @ian Or, as they appear in order on the mode dial: P, Tv, Av, M

Comment: Or in alphabetical order: Av-M-P-Tv

Comment: Or upside down and backwards: ʌʇ-d-ɯ-ʌɐ